# Setting Modal Presentation Style causing views to disappear (Xcode 6)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, presentviewcontroller

I have set up my view in interface builder. I am using auto layout which has been set up also.

If I present my view with the following code:

```
GlossaryViewController *glossaryViewController = [[GlossaryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GlossaryViewController" bundle:nil];
glossaryViewController.delegate = self;
glossaryViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;

[self presentViewController:glossaryViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Then everything works fine. However if I change modalPresentationStyle to a smaller style such as UIModalPresentationFormSheet then none of my views are visible when the view appears.

I have even tried testing it with just a UIImageView that is set to hug the four edges. Even this disappears.

Before I upgrade to Xcode 6 I had created similar views that still work fine. This has only occurred when creating a new xib.

Has anyone else had similar issues?

Answer (score 0):

After deleting the app, deleting the troublesome nib, doing a clean, restarting xcode and then recreating the xib I still have not be able to get this to work. This was after attempts at changing the size of the view, orientation and playing around with auto layout.

The behaviour is rather odd. Sometimes a single view might show but adding any others by it does nothing.

I have hopefully found a work around for now. If you do as follows:

- Click on files owner and then go to the 'Show file inspector' tab.
- Next look for 'Interface builder document'. Under this heading is 'Opens in'. Change this from 6 to 5.1.

The following popup appears. (**WARNING**: if seems once you have clicked 'Disable size classes' there is no going back. So make sure it's what you want to do):

[image]

Select the option you want to keep. So if the xib is just for iPhone then select iPhone. This will then give you back the way it was in xcode 5. Basically it's converting it back to a xib that handles either iPhone or iPad and not both.

Look forward to hopefully someone being able to explain what I am doing wrong or if there is some sort of issue with interface builder at this moment in time. Be good use the new interface builder instead of switching back to xcode 5.1 xib interface.